# What version of MS Paint shipped with Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, microsoft-paint

I'm looking to find which versions of Microsoft Paint shipped with each version of Windows so I can update [Wikipedia's release history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Paint#History).

Wikipedia's current list includes general changes between versions of Paint, but it doesn't include any specific version numbers. It also seems to be missing a few versions. (*The Windows 10 Creators Update added an "[Open Paint 3D](http://winaero.com/blog/classic-paint-got-integration-paint-3d/)" button*)

I wasn't able to find any official Microsoft update documentation or changelog history for MS Paint. On my personal computer I found that that Windows 7 Service Pack 1 includes Paint 6.1, while Ben N reported having [version 5.1 on Windows XP](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38859225#38859225), but that still leaves out Windows Vista.

**What version of MS Paint shipped with Windows Vista?**

[image: Windows 7 - MS Paint 6.1]

Comment: Look closely: The dialog does not indicate the *Paint* version, but the *Windows* version instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your personal computer you found that that Windows 7 Service Pack 1 includes Paint 6.1, while Ben N reported having version 5.1 on Windows XP. These are version numbers of Windows, not Paint specifically (as Daniel B pointed out). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions

So, the answer is: MS Paint version 6.0 was shipped with Windows Vista, because Windows Vista is Windows version 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Running old versions of Microsoft Paint (from Windows 98, XP and/or Vista) on Windows 7, the about box is identical: clearly it reports either the current Windows version or the version of the Windows 7 edition of Microsoft Paint that is installed.

File properties in Windows Explorer, on the other hand, include a version number from the executable in the *Details* tab.